# Going round in Circles..Buffering/ArcObjects/VBA

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I've just started learning VBA and ArcObjects, and at the moment just playing around trying to do different things. 
What i am trying to do is Click on a tool, and allow the user to put a point graphic on the map, but also buffer the point(marker) that has been added. I can get the point on the map, but seem to be going round in circles getting the buffer to work. Can someone give me some hints ( i don't want the exact answer just some guidance on where I am going wrong.

Code is here.

```
Private Sub Buffer_MouseDown(ByVal button As Long, ByVal shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument ' Create Object for current document
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument ' Set object to current Document

Dim pMap As IMap ' Create object for current map
Set pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap ' Set object to the current active map

Dim pPoint As IPoint 'Create object for point on map
Set pPoint = pMxDoc.CurrentLocation '  Set object to current location

Dim pElement As IElement ' Create object for graphic THAT IS ADDED TO THE MAP!!!!
Set pElement = New MarkerElement ' Set object to a new marker element (point graphic)

pElement.Geometry = pPoint ' Assign the geometry of the element to the Point.

Dim pGraphics As IGraphicsContainer ' Create object to hold the graphic
Set pGraphics = pMap ' Set object to current active map

pGraphics.AddElement pElement, 0 '  Set the graphic that will be added

Dim pActiveView As IActiveView ' Create object for active map display
Set pActiveView = pMxDoc.ActiveView ' Set object to the Active view

'--------------CREATE BUFFER------------------------'

 Dim pSpaRef As ISpatialReference3
 Set pSpaRef = pMap.SpatialReference

 Dim pFCBuffer As IFeatureCursorBuffer2 ' Create Object for buffer
 Set pFCBuffer = New FeatureCursorBuffer ' Set object for new buffer

 pFCBuffer.Dissolve = True
 pFCBuffer.ValueDistance = 100
 Set pFCBuffer.BufferSpatialReference = pSpaRef
 Set pFCBuffer.DataFrameSpatialReference = pSpaRef
 Set pFCBuffer.SourceSpatialReference = pSpaRef
 Set pFCBuffer.TargetSpatialReference = pSpaRef


 Dim pCGLayer As ICompositeGraphicsLayer2
 Set pCGLayer = New CompositeGraphicsLayer

 Dim pGLayer As IGraphicsLayer
 Set pGLayer = pMap.ActiveGraphicsLayer


 pFCBuffer.BufferToGraphics pGLayer



   pActiveView.PartialRefresh esriViewGraphics, pElement, Nothing ' [partial refresh of the graphics element.

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Halil,

The interface you are using to create the buffers *IFeatureCursorBuffer2* creates buffers for *selected features*.  Your point that you create based upon the users button click is not a feature but a *graphic* which you are adding to the graphics container of the map. A *Feature* is essentially a row in a table or *featureclass*.

As you are adding your point as a graphic I assume the buffer you want to create will also end up as a graphic. Use the interface *ITopologicalOperator* and it's method *Buffer* to create a polygon then do as you did with your point, create a graphic element.

Comment: Duncun, 
 i have added the following

Dim pTopoOp As ITopologicalOperator2

Dim pBuffPoly As IPolygon

Set pTopoOp = pPoint.GeometryType

Set pBuffPoly = pTopoOp.Buffer(1000)

but I get a type mismatch error on line 3, i've also tried Set pTopoOp = pElement.Geometry but get the same mismatch error.

Halil

Comment: The line "Set pTopoOp = pPoint.GeometryType" should be "Set pTopoOp = pPoint"